# How to count group of consecutive values by observation in R

Tags: r

I simply want to count the number of groups of consecutive zeros in R.  The 'TotalObsCount' is the desired output.  I know I'm on the right track with the below code but I can't seem to tweak it correctly.
Example Dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 col2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                 col3 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                 col4 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 col5 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1))

TotalObsCount <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Example of code

```
    most_consecutive_val = function(x, val = 0) {with(rle(x), if(all(values != val)) 0 else max(lengths[values == val]))}
    apply(df[-1], MARGIN = 1, most_consecutive_val)
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly why TotalObsCount starts with `1 2`?

Comment: Are you looking for `apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(rle(x)$values == "0")))`?

Comment: @Maël I'm aiming to count consecutive zeros for each observation.  Therefore in the first row there is 3 consecutive zeros in a row, 1 for total.  Next row there are two groups of consecutive zeros therefore 2, 1 next row etc.

Comment: @AllanCameron the issue I run into is that it counts a zero by itself.  Therefore, if you look at the 1st observation there is 1 consecutive run of zeros but the result returns 2.

Comment: @cmdublin ah - you didn't specify that in your question, and also using this rule can you explain why the fourth entry of `TotalObsCount` is 2? You have one group of two zeros and one single zero - why is the result 2?

Comment: @AllanCameron apologies I wasn't clear.  And I counted wrong on the 4th entry, that should be 1 as only two zeros consecutively together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```r
apply(df, 1, function(x) length(which(rle(x)$values == "0" & rle(x)$lengths > 1)))
#> [1] 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: slight variation on the great answer above using `rle` taking the sum of the T/F results. I also think it is more elegant to call `rle` only once: `apply(df, MARGIN = 1, function(x) { x <- rle(x); sum(x$values == 0 & x$lengths > 1) })`